# Three.VRControls initial rotation

Tags: three.js, virtual-reality

I've been doing through this [Unable to change camera position when using VRControls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34470248/unable-to-change-camera-position-when-using-vrcontrols) and [Three.js - VRControls integration - How to move in the scene?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30511524/three-js-vrcontrols-integration-how-to-move-in-the-scene) but it's not quite doing what I need.

I have a VR video app and I've just switched to VRControls with the WebVR polyfill from something old and custom. This is working well, however I'm really struggling to set the initial camera angle.

I.e. I want the camera to start pointing at a particular angle, and then rotate with the controls - however the controls always override this angle.

I've tried adding the camera to a Dolly Group or Persepective Camera, and it seems like I can move the camera but not set the initial viewing angle.

Here is how the camera is set up

```
    container = document.getElementById('container');

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1024);

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    target = new THREE.Vector3();

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    var vrEffect = new THREE.VREffect(renderer);
        vrEffect.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    var params = {
        hideButton: false, // Default: false.
        isUndistorted: false // Default: false.
    };
    manager = new WebVRManager(renderer, vrEffect, params);
    dolly = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera();
    dolly.add( camera );
    //scene.add( dolly );
    controls = new THREE.VRControls(camera);// (I've tried using Dolly here)
    controls.standing = true;
```

And I've tried various ways to rotate the camera, dolly or scene

```
    camera.position.y = currentScene.pan * Math.PI/180;
    //controls.resetPose();
    //dolly.position.x = currentScene.tilt * Math.PI/180;
    //camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
```

I can rotate the mesh, but then all the objects inside the mesh are in the wrong place.. I could try moving them but this seems like the wrong approach to point the camera to the place I want it..

Comment: Have you tried to rotate the dolly group?   dolly.rotation.x = 50*Math.PI/180;

Answer (score 0):

The camera was getting re-added to the scene at a later time, overriding the dolly. It's working now.